# How do I remove the bottom border on a bootstrap 3.0 table thead?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a new project I'm working on, and I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.

I have a table with class "table" (and no more), it has a thead and tbody in it's DOM.
There aren't any borders in the tbody, but in the thead there is a small white (or nearly white) border that, for the life of me, I cannot get to go away.

Here is the website where the table is located:
http://majornoob.com/dev/mcsr/

If I can be of more assistance to helping in resolving my question, I'd be most happy to edit the post.

### **EDIT**

Here is my modified version of the accepted answer, as I'm just removing the borders and am not modifying anything else:

```
.table thead>tr>th,.table tbody>tr>th,.table tfoot>tr>th,.table thead>tr>td,.table tbody>tr>td,.table tfoot>tr>td{border:none;}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can remove this border:

In `css` file you can see :

In bootstrap you have following CSS For set `border-bottom` on table head elements:

```
.table thead>tr>th {
   vertical-align: bottom;
   border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
}
```

And following CSS for set `border-top` on table row elements:

```
.table thead>tr>th,.table tbody>tr>th,.table tfoot>tr>th,.table thead>tr>td,.table tbody>tr>td,.table tfoot>tr>td{
   padding:8px;
   line-height:1.428571429;
   vertical-align:top;
   border-top:1px solid #ddd
}
```

By removing these two border style, you can easily get success and what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be accepting the other answer however, since he has already solved the problem for me. Your information is valuable also, though!

Answer (score 6):

here is the border:

```
.table thead>tr>th {
vertical-align: bottom;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

you can edit it as you like.

---

## update:

edit this class too:

```
.table thead>tr>th, .table tbody>tr>th, .table tfoot>tr>th, .table thead>tr>td, .table tbody>tr>td, .table tfoot>tr>td {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was extremely quick, however having made this change there is an even thinner very light line. Can you help me locate the problem snippet? Thanks in advance.